# Rails: Is there a way to require authentication to view a json file while still referencing it from javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

In my rails app, I have a page that accesses data from a JSON file. However, I want to prevent the JSON file from being accessed directly with its URL without the user being authenticated.

I've tried putting the file in the assets pipeline, but it's still accessible from a URL without authentication, just the URL has an additional string of random characters inside of it. I'd also rather not paste the entirety of the JSON into the javascript file, because at later stages the project will be integrating multiple JSON files some of which will reach sizes of 50 MB and which may also be updated periodically.

Is there a way I can keep the JSON file totally secure from outside access while still allowing Javascript to use it? If not, are there any alternatives that would be relatively easy to implement?

Comment: If you're accessing it from rails app, why don't you put it in a folder where files can't be accessed? If authenticated user wants to access it, read it from rails and render it as a response. **Never** let your users have access directly to the server's file system.

Comment: I'm currently using javascript to read the JSON files because I want to be able to change which JSON file is loaded while staying on the same page. Is there a way to render them through rails as a response to a jquery event?

Comment: Make it like an api, you make a $.ajax request and return the json with rails. But never let users have direct access to file systems, that's a bad idea.